# Smoothing a line with Gnuplot not working as expected when using different colors depending on data value

Tags: gnuplot

This is the config I have and that works as intended to color the temperature curve blue if it is under 20C and red if it is 20C or above.

```
set datafile separator ","
set title "CO2,  Temp"
set key bottom right

set linetype 11 linecolor rgb "red"
set linetype 12 linecolor rgb "blue"

unset grid
set grid x
set grid y2

set ylabel "ppm"
set y2label "°C"

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"  

set y2tics 
set y2range [15:30]  # range for temp


plot "minimonlog.csv" using 1:2 with lines smooth bezier axes x1y1 title "Co2", \
     "minimonlog.csv" using 1:3:($3 < 20 ? 12 : 11) linecolor variable with lines axes x1y2 title "Temp" 

done = 0
bind all 'd' 'done = 1'
while(!done) {
    replot
    pause 5      # waiting time in seconds
}
```

The csv contains data like this:

```
2023-10-25 14:10:40,   505,  20.35
2023-10-25 14:10:50,   506,  20.35
2023-10-25 14:11:00,   506,  20.35
2023-10-25 14:11:10,   506,  20.48
```

I tried adding in "smooth bezier" expecting it to smooth the temperature line, but this did not work. The line got smooth, but the color difference disappeared.

```
plot "minimonlog.csv" using 1:2 with lines smooth bezier axes x1y1 title "Co2", \
     "minimonlog.csv" using 1:3:($3 < 20 ? 12 : 11) linecolor variable with lines smooth bezier axes x1y2 title
```

The error I get:

```
"minimon.gp" line 24: warning: extra columns ignored by smoothing option
"minimon.gp" line 29: warning: extra columns ignored by smoothing option
"minimon.gp" line 30: warning: extra columns ignored by smoothing option
"minimon.gp" line 30: warning: extra columns ignored by smoothing option
"minimon.gp" line 33: internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, `smooth bezier` does not accept more than 2 columns.

A possible workaround would be the following:

- plot your data using `smooth bezier` into a table/datablock
- plot this datablock with conditional color

**Script:**

```
### plot smooth bezier curve with conditional color
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(20+sin(x)+rand(0)-0.5) w table
unset table

myColor(v) = v<20 ? 0x0000ff : 0xff0000
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 2,1

    plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor($2)) w lp pt 7 lc rgb var

    set table $Smooth
        set samples 50
        plot $Data u 1:2 smooth bezier
    unset table
    plot $Smooth u 1:2:(myColor($2)) w lp pt 7 lc rgb var

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (example for timedata)

Actually, I noticed that time data and comma separated data will be trickier in your case:

- plotting to a datablock using `smooth` and `with table` do not work together
- when plotting to a datablock without `with table`, apparently you cannot set `separator comma`. So, you have to switch to `separator whitespace`.
- plotting timedata to a datablock puts the timedata into quotes. As a consequence you cannot plot your timedata later as `plot $Data u 1:2`, but have to use `plot $Data u (strptime(myTimeFmt,strcol(1))):2`.

Maybe somebody has some suggestions to simplify.

**Script:**

```
### plot smooth bezier *timedata* curve with conditional color
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set timefmt myTimeFmt

# create some test data
set table $Data separator comma
    plot '+' u (strftime(myTimeFmt,time(0)+$0*3600)):(20+sin(x)+rand(0)-0.5) w table
unset table

myColor(v) = v<=20 ? 0x0000ff : 0xff0000
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set datafile separator comma
    set format x "%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M" timedate
    plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor($2)) w lp pt 7 lc rgb var

    set table $Smooth
        set samples 50
        set format x myTimeFmt timedate
        plot $Data u 1:2 smooth bezier
    unset table
    set datafile separator whitespace
    set format x "%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M" timedate
    plot $Smooth u (strptime(myTimeFmt,strcol(1))):2:(myColor($2)) w lp pt 7 lc rgb var

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition 2:** (example with real data)

Ok, a few more specialities with your data.

- your data contains some `nan`
- `NaN` will "mess up" `smooth`. In order to avoid that you need to `set datafile missing NaN`

In the example below I don't use the systax `set xdata time`, but then you need in the plot command e.g. `(timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt))`.

- when plotting to the datablocks `$CO2` and `$Temp` I am using `format "%.0f" numeric` which are seconds passed since Jan, 1st 1970.
- when plotting the format x is set to `"%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M" timedate` and you can simply plot, e.g. `plot $CO2 u 1:2 ...`.

Plotting time/date data can be a bit confusing.

**Script:**

```
### plot smooth bezier *timedata* curve with conditional color
reset session

FILE = "SO77359398.csv"
set datafile separator comma
set datafile missing NaN

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set ylabel  "CO_2 / ppm"
set ytics  nomirror
set y2label "Temperature / °C"
set y2tics nomirror

myColor(v) = v<20 ?  0x0000ff : 0xff0000
set key noautotitle top center

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set format x "%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M" timedate
    plot FILE u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w l lc "dark-grey" axes x1y1 ti "CO_2", \
           '' u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3:(myColor($3)) w l lc rgb var axes x1y2 ti "Temperature"
           
    set samples 500
    set format x "%.0f" numeric
    set table $CO2
        plot FILE u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 smooth bezier
    set table $Temp
        plot FILE u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3 smooth bezier
    unset table
    set datafile separator whitespace
    set format x "%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M" timedate
    plot $CO2 u 1:2 w l lc "dark-grey" axes x1y1 ti "CO_2", \
        $Temp u 1:2:(myColor($2)) w l lc rgb var axis x1y2 ti "Temperature"
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Works great with example data, but I can't figure out how to adopt it to my real data.

Comment: @Ocean Can you maybe be a bit more specific? What do you get? (error messages, wrong output, etc.?) What is the script you tried?

Comment: I get "Skipping data file with no valid points" and "x range is invalid" for the line where it's supposed to plot $Data, when trying to plot my own data instead of the example data. I'm surely doing something wrong, but I don't know what. Here's my data: https://files.catbox.moe/fttizx.csv

Comment: @Ocean thanks for providing original data. I guess there is the reason. You have `NaN` in your data. Check the 3rd example in the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I wouldn't have guessed that some error values in the data were to blame.